# jbuilder 1.0 installation failure with 4.04.0+spacetime on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I am using OCaml 4.05.0+spacetime in order to profile my app's memory usage. However, I fail to install jbuilder 1.0 with this compiler. The error message

```
# opam-version 1.2.2 (aa258ecc06d3aea5a67f442a4ffd23f2a457180b)
# os           linux
# command      ocaml bootstrap.ml
# path         /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/build/jbuilder.1.0+beta14
# compiler     4.04.0+spacetime
# exit-code    137
# env-file     /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/build/jbuilder.1.0+beta14/jbuilder-23292-ffb3fd.env
# stdout-file  /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/build/jbuilder.1.0+beta14/jbuilder-23292-ffb3fd.out
# stderr-file  /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/build/jbuilder.1.0+beta14/jbuilder-23292-ffb3fd.err
### stdout ###
# /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/bin/ocamllex.opt -q src/sexp_lexer.mll
# /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/bin/ocamllex.opt -q src/meta_lexer.mll
# /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/bin/ocamldep.opt -modules src/action.ml src/action_intf.ml src/alias.ml src/ansi_color.ml src/arg_spec.ml src/artifacts.ml src/bin.ml src/build.ml src/build_interpret.ml src/build_system.ml src/clflags.ml src/cm_kind.ml src/config.ml src/context.ml src/file_tree.ml src/findlib.ml src/future.ml src/gen_meta.ml src/gen_rules.ml src/glob_lexer.boot.ml src/import.ml src/install.ml src/io.ml src/jbuild.ml src/jbuild_load.ml vendor/boot/jbuilder_opam_file_format.ml vendor/boot/jbuilder_re.ml src/js_of_ocaml_rules.ml src/lib.ml src/lib_db.ml src/loc.ml src/log.ml src/main.ml src/merlin.ml src/meta.ml src/meta_lexer.ml src/ml_kind.ml src/mode.ml src/module.ml src/module_compilation.ml src/ocaml_flags.ml src/ocamldep.ml src/odoc.ml src/opam_file.ml src/ordered_set_lang.ml src/package.ml src/path.ml src/sexp.ml src/sexp_lexer.ml src/string_with_vars.ml src/super_context.ml src/top_closure.ml src/utils.ml src/utop.ml src/vfile_kind.ml src/watermarks.ml src/workspace.ml > boot-depends.txt
# /home/opam/.opam/4.04.0+spacetime/bin/ocamlopt.opt -w -40 -o boot.exe unix.cmxa boot.ml
### stderr ###
# Killed
```

This problem also occurs with OCaml 4.05.0+spacetime. My machine runs Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried on macOS X and this problem does not come up. So this could be a Linux-specific problem.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: 4.04.0 or 4.05.0?  Anyway, `opam` shows only the last few lines of build log and your information is not enough to guess what has happend.  Compile the package by hand.  I would just ask at https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues

Comment: Thanks. It works normally on 4.04.0 and 4.05.0. I guess the installation fails because 4.05.0+spacetime takes too much memory and Unix kills it because of that.